# How to access a `declare`d variable from unit tests Angular & Karma/Jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have something like this in my Code :

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  AlertController,
  App,
  Events,
  Platform
} from "ionic-angular";

declare
let PushNotification: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'push',
  template: ``
})
export class PushComponent implements OnInit {

  nav: any;
  _push: any;
```

I want to access this `declare let PushNotification: any;` in my unit test so that I can assign it a mock value. How can I access this variable?

Comment: how do you use this variable in your code?

Comment: @Andrei in code this variable is initialized and loaded with an external lib code. So We just make calls like PushNotification.get_Notification().

Comment: so it seems it is global. provide mock as `window.PushNotification = ...`